# Use unique_ptr and appropriate container to do memory management

Tags: c++, c++11, memory-management, containers, smart-pointers

First of all, my motivation is to do efficient memory management on top of a C like computational kernel. And I tried to use the `std::unique_ptr` and `std::vector`, my code looks like below

```
// my data container
typedef std::unique_ptr<double> my_type;
std::vector<my_type> my_storage;

// when I need some memory for computation kernel
my_storage.push_back(my_type());
my_storage.back.reset(new double[some_length]);

// get pointer to do computational stuff
double *p_data=my_storage.back.get();
```

Notice here in practice **`p_data`** may be stored in some other container(e.g. map) to indexing each allocated array according to the domain problem, nevertheless, my main questions are

1. Here is `std::vector` a good choice? what about other container like `std::list`/`set`?
2. Is there fundamental problem with my allocation method?
3. Suppose after I use **`p_data`** for some operations, now I want to release the memory chunk pointed by the raw pointer **`p_data`**, what is the best practice here?

Comment: If you `p_data` is expected to be shared between different containers, you may use `std::shared_ptr` instead, and then you do not use raw pointer at all.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<double[]>`, if you use `new double[]`, and prefer `std::make_unique` to avoid this mismatch.

Comment: @Mine: this could be totally a waste of resources according to OP specification of the problem which is unclear.

Comment: @Jarod42: `std::make_unique()` is not in C++11, it was added in C++14.

Comment: @mine shared between different containers? p_data in my case is stored in a map where value is the address, so I guess in my case it's ownership is unique. perhaps you can give some concrete example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you are allocating an array you need to use the specialization `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` or you won't get a `delete []` on memory release but a simple `delete`.

`std::vector` is a good choice unless you have any explicit reason to use something different. For example, if you are going to move many elements inside the container then a `std::list` could perform better (less `memmove` operations to shift things around).

Regarding how to manage memory, it depends mainly on the pattern of utilization. If `my_storage` is mainly responsible for everything (which in your specification it is, since `unique_ptr` expresses ownership), it means that it will be the only one who can release memory. Which could be done simply by calling `my_storage[i].reset()`.

Mind that storing raw pointers of managed objects inside other collections leads to dangling pointers if memory is released, for example:

```
using my_type = std::unique_ptr<double[]>;
using my_storage = std::vector<my_type>;

my_storage data;
data.push_back(my_type(new double[100]));

std::vector<double*> rawData;
rawData.push_back(data[0].get());

data.clear(); // delete [] is called on array and memory is released
*rawData[0] = 1.2; // accessing a dangling pointer -> bad
```

This could be a problem or not, if `data` is released by last then there are no problems, otherwise you could store const references to `std::unique_ptr` so that at least you'd be able to check if memory is still valid, e.g.:

```
using my_type = std::unique_ptr<double[]>;
using my_managed_type = std::reference_wrapper<const my_type>;
std::vector<my_managed_type> rawData;
```

Comment: in this case, vector stores the shared_ptr, so here perhaps std::list wouldn't have much benefit even if we may swap the pointer(memory)?

Answer (score 1):

Using `std::unique_ptr` with any STL container , including `std::vector`, is fine in general.  But you are not using `std::unique_ptr` the correct way (you are not using the array specialized version of it), and you don't need to resort to using `back.reset()` at all.  Try this instead:

```
// my data container
typedef std::unique_ptr<double[]> my_type;
// or: using my_type = std::unique_ptr<double[]>;

std::vector<my_type> my_storage;

my_type ptr(new double[some_length]);
my_storage.push_back(std::move(ptr));
// or: my_storage.push_back(my_type(new double[some_length]));
// or: my_storage.emplace_back(new double[some_length]);
```